# How do I create a bigger font in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm currently assigned to help with a project to create a system for scheduling, I don't have a lot of experience with Java FX so I was wondering if someone can help me with this.

I'm trying to make the font of the Administrator log in bigger. Here is the code.

```
@Override
public Region getView() {
    VBox content = new VBox(72);
    content.setId("center");
    content.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);



    Label message = new Label("Administrator Log In");


    JFXButton ok = new JFXButton("OK");
    ok.setGraphic(FontAwesome.getFontAwesomeLabel(FontAwesome.CHECK, 72));
    ok.setButtonType(ButtonType.RAISED);

    content.getChildren().addAll(message,ok);

    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc ([*Oracle Doc*](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/label.htm#sthref17)), there is different ways :

- Use a `constructor` of the `Font` class

  ```
  label1.setFont(new Font(30));
  label1.setFont(new Font("Arial", 30));
  ```
- Use a `static` method of the `Font` class

  ```
  label2.setFont(Font.font(32));
  label2.setFont(Font.font("Cambria", 32));
  ```

---

There is others constructor in the `Font` class : [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 message.setFont(new Font("Arial", SIZE_OF_FONT));
```